# Image upload AngularJs to Rails4 API

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, content-type, paperclip-validation

I have an angularJs app that sends a base64 encoded image (or file) to my rails4 server api that uses paperclip to store attachments. Everything works fine until the `content_type_validation` paperclip does.

For some reason, paperclip determines the content-type's been spoofed and get the following error message:

`[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 1413325092.jpg (["image/jpeg"]), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream; charset=binary. See documentation to allow this combination.`

I create the paperclip attachment with the following code:

```
    def self.create_from_base64(base64_string)
        decoded_data = Base64.decode64(base64_string) 
        # create 'file' understandable by Paperclip
        data = StringIO.new(decoded_data)
        data.class_eval do
        attr_accessor :content_type, :original_filename
        end
        # set file properties
        data.content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
        data.original_filename = "#{Time.now.to_i}.jpg"
    end
```

I've tried different things but for some reason even when I set `data.content_type = 'application/octet-stream'`, the error is exactly the same, and paperclip it's been spoofed.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

EDIT:

I have the following validation:

`validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/, /application\/octet-stream*/]`

Comment: hi @scanales, I am also trying to upload image using paperclip with Rails and Angularjs. But I failed to send to rails controller from Angularjs controller. How did you manage do to it. Could you please explain it?

Comment: @Vieenay I used websocketrails to send it as a base64 encoded string.